MacBook Pro running Linux Xubuntu charger getting concerningly hot
The title pretty much says it all. It's not exactly a problem or issue, but I have a 2013 MacBook Pro running Linux Xubuntu natively (not dualboot or VM) and the charging port where it plugs into and the charging brick itself gets VERY hot.
I'm just concerned it could be a fire hazard and/or damage a component. Does running Linux on a MacBook Pro have an history or issue with the charger?
When I run $cat /etc/os-release  I get the following output:
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

I'm pretty sure THIS 2013 MacBook Pro model is mine. But some of the main specs are:
- quad-core Intel Core i7
- 16GB of 1600MHz DDR3L onboard memory
- Intel Iris Pro Graphics and NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M with 2GB of GDDR5 (although I'm pretty sure I'm using only the Intel Iris graphics)

I'm hoping to hear from others that have Linux running on the same or similar hardware and just reconfirm that it getting so hot is normal and not a cause for concern. Any input would be appreciated!

Does it occur also when the laptop is off and charging? If so then it's obviously unrelated to the OS and no, there are no such reports that I've heard of.

I don't usually leave it plugged in while I have it off. I'll give it a try and see what happens. Thanks for the suggestion!
